# jquery click function inside a for loop

Tags: for-loop

I have this code. For some reason the 1st console.log prints out well in the console but the 2nd gives me an undefined when I click. The cvs array is global. 
thanks for the help

```
var losotro = ['div.santiago', 'div.karina', 'div.roman', 'div.marcos'];
var cvs = ['div#cv0 p', 'div#cv1 p', 'div#cv2 p', 'div#cv3 p'];
    for (i = 0; i < losotro.length; i++) {
       console.log(cvs[i]);
       jQuery(losotro[i]).click(function(){
          console.log(cvs[i]);       
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical closure problem in JavaScript.

Basically, all the callback(the click event handlers) are referencing to the same variable `i`(I know, this is weird to me at first as well), which at the end of the loop should be `losotro.length`. And
 absolutely this is out of the index range of the `losotro` array.

You may want to check how closure works in JavaScript. But for the current problem, you could do this.

```
var cvs = ['div#cv0 p', 'div#cv1 p', 'div#cv2 p', 'div#cv3 p'];
for (i = 0; i < losotro.length; i++) {
   console.log(cvs[i]);
   var bindedFunc = (function(i) {
      return function() {
         console.log(i)
      }
   })(i)
   jQuery(losotro[i]).click(bindedFunc);
}
```